# Does Java access all threads automatically?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm not very knowledgeable on multi-threading in Java. But after a brief search online I saw people creating classes implementing the Thread class and starting these new thread objects, or something along those lines. I also saw a higher level concurrency library.

At the moment I have written a very simple program and have it running with absolutely nothing optimised for multi-threaded processers.

However, when I run the program from the terminal and check my Activity Monitor (Task manager) I notice 100% of CPU is being used. Hence, all threads must are being accessed. Is this right? Does this mean there is no reason to implement threading in the code I write?

Will my program use all CPU threads without me telling it to do so?

I remember writing a C++ program months back and this was not the case. It was showing 50% CPU usage for each program I ran.

Here is my Activity Monitor:

[image]

Comment: Nothing "accesses" your program's threads:  Your threads do work.  Each of your threads is either able to do work (a.k.a., _runnable_), or else it is waiting for something (a.k.a., _blocked_), or else it is _dead_.  The operating system _scheduler_'s job is to make sure that every runnable thread has a CPU to run on or, if there are more runnable threads than CPUs, it makes the threads take turns.

Comment: This behavior is not normal. There is something is your code that keep spinning the CPU at full speed. Please share your code for further help. BTW **every Java process is multithreaded** even though you are not creating any thread. At least there is one user thread main thread and other JVM maintenance threads that handle like garbage collection, finalization etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that CPU usage is per-core. It uses 99.1% of a single core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hence, all threads must are being accessed. Is this right? Does this mean there is no reason to implement threading in the code I write?

A java program requires a Thread to run - for a program launched via the main method this is the main thread launched by the JRE. If all the computation is within this method, it is running on a single thread (and in theory on a single CPU). If the process/computation can be parallelized, there is reason to do so, and there is sufficient CPU available then launching more threads can speed up the process (within reason relative to the number of CPU's)

> Will my program use all CPU threads without me telling it to do so?

The OS will distribute to the CPU's. This being said, a thread is a serial computation...meaning that it cannot be distributed to two CPU's at the same time. As a result, running a single java thread (that does not sleep or wait) on a 2 CPU computer should result in 50% total CPU usage by the application (on a 4 CPU this goes down to 25%, and so on...)

Comment: As you can see above my program is using 99% CPU. I haven't explicitly given my program access to multiple CPU cores. Does this mean that threads created for my program are being run on both CPUs (I have dual-core), i.e - 7 threads in Core 1 and 7 threads Core 2. Hence, the reason it is using full CPU?

Comment: If the Activity Monitor is anything like 'top' for 'nix systems, then this percentage is relative to a single CPU, not all of them. You should have a system level CPU usage monitory which would provide a different perspective

Answer (score 0):

No, Java doesn't automatically use multithreading.
If you want to split a load between multiple threads, you have to create instance of the Thread or Runnable class or use some framework or library which would do it for you.

Comment: Just to point out even though you are not creating thread (main thread is the one that start your code), there are always other threads running in JVM like garbage collection, finalizer (should avoid using finalize) etc. That means by default every java process is Multi Threaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super sure what you are asking, so I will try to answer the best I can.

> Will my program use all CPU threads without me telling it to do so?

No, your program will only use as many threads as it needs.  It also (under normal circumstances) cannot access threads that belong to other processes so even if your CPU was pegging out it more than likely has to how the professor is assigning time slices than java taking up a bunch of threads.

[More info on time slicing and preemptive multitasking.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing))

Answer (score 0):

<sub>From the way the question is written, there seems to be a basic misunderstanding of the words "thread" and "CPU" (or rather "CPU core"). Other answers and further resources may help to clarify this.</sub>

<sub>Apart from that, these "activity monitors" are usually not the most precise way to measure things.</sub>

---

But the answer to the actual question is: **Yes**: Even a (seemingly) single-threaded Java Program can use multiple cores and cause such a high load.

The most likely scenario here is: Garbage collection. There are parallel garbage collectors (see [Hotspot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) for details). And if your program is causing lots of garbage, or the heap size is just too small, causing the garbage collector to work very hard to prevent an `OutOfMemoryError`, then this can explain the high workload on multiple cores.

---

<sub>Another possible reason may be "hidden" parallelism that is not caused by explicit user threads. You don't have to explicitly create a thread with `new Thread(...)` in every case. For example, the new Java 8 streams API may use multiple threads (and thus, impose load on multiple cores) with the parallel threads that are offered. But from the question, this seems unlikely here.</sub>